# How to find the eigenvalues of a $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the four distinct eigenvalues of the following matrix. $$\begin{pmatrix}3&-2&5&5\\0&2&6&6\\-5&2&-9&-7\\5&-2&5&3\end{pmatrix}$$ Using row reduction is not allowed.

---

I am taking my first linear algebra class and came over this task. Sarrus only works for $3 \times 3$ matrices. How can I solve for this $4 \times 4$ matrices? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go back to the definition of the determinant and how to compute determinants of large matrices  (Hint: Laplace expansion).

Comment: Elementary row/column operations are usually the easiest way to go

Comment: You can use the Laplace expansion on the second row.

Comment: Umm....   are you able to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of  $$ M = \left( \begin{array}{rr} 23 & 42 \\ -9 & -16 \end{array}  \right) \; \; ? \; \; \;   $$

Comment: I was told elementary row/column operations would skew the result of the eigenvalue. And with laplace i get 3 equations, which seem to only allow me to solve for 3 variables!

Comment: Yes Will! my techniques work for up to 3 rows.

Comment: Stanley, please do the 2 by 2 example I constructed

Comment: A method to find eigenvalues is to solve $\lambda$ for equation $|\lambda I-A|=0$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Have you already learnt that?

Comment: Yes zhang! im able to solve for matrices up to 3 values. the fourth is creating some difficulty as i cant use sarrus unless i use laplace expansion, which only gives me 3 equations for 3 unknowns

Comment: Will, i computed your question and got eigenvalue 5 and 2

Comment: @Stanley  good.  Now please find the (column) eigenvectors

Comment: I am only looking for a way to solve for the eigenvalues in this example, but ill try to compute it as well

Comment: I guess I have a way for you to continue, based on the comment of @Zhang  .  You may write   down the new matrix which is $ A - xI  \; . \; \;$    Then you may reduce by row operations, getting an upper traingular matrix,  where the diagonal elements are of the form  $x - \lambda_i $     which shows you what values of $x$ makes the matrix singular; and those are the eigenvalues

Comment: Ill try doing that, thank you!

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial will be found by the determinant:
$$p(\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix}
3-\lambda & -2 & 5 &5 \\ 
0 & 2 & 6 & 6\\ 
 -5& 2 & -9-\lambda & -7\\ 
 -5& -2 & 5 &3-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
3-\lambda & -2 & 5 & 5\\ 
0 & 2-\lambda & 6 & 6\\ 
0 & 0 &  -4-\lambda& -4-\lambda\\ 
5 & -2 & 5 &3-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}=-(\lambda+4) \begin{vmatrix}
3-\lambda & -2 & 5 & 5\\ 
0 & 2-\lambda & 6 & 6\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
5 & -2 & 5 &3-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}= -(4+\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
3-\lambda & -2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2-\lambda & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
5 & -2 & 5 &3-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}=-(4+\lambda)(2-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
3-\lambda & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 1\\ 
5 & 5 & 3-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=-(4+\lambda)(2-\lambda)(3-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
5 & 3-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=(4+\lambda)(2-\lambda)(3-\lambda)(2+\lambda)$$
You can reach this by using only simple properties of the determinants, without row reduction.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, merely a comment. It turns out you can use row reduction to find the eigenvalues. Please see [eigenvalues by row reduction](https://www.unk.edu/academics/math/_files/eigenvalues-by-row-operations.pdf).  The paper also details a simple computational technique for finding the eigenvalues of square matrices by the method of McWorter and Meyers.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:For finding determinant of those matrix whose size is bigger than $3 \times 3$ , remember that the determinant of upper (or lower) triangular matrix is equal to product of the elements in its diagonal.

Comment: I understand! Is this only the case for matrices 4x4 or larger?

Comment: @Stanley it is valid for every $n \times n$ , such as $12 \times 12$ etc.

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately i dont have rep to vote.